# Form for multiple models

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have two models:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    # other stuff


class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    body = models.TextField()
    # other stuff
```

And I want to create a form contains two fields: `Topic.title` and `Post.body`. Of course, I can create the following form:

```
class TopicForm(Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    body = forms.TextField()
    # and so on
```

But I don't want to duplicate code, since I already have `title` and `body` in models. I'm looking for something like this:

```
class TopicForm(MagicForm):
    class Meta:
        models = (Topic, Post)
        fields = {
            Topic: ('title', ),
            Post: ('body', )
        }
    # and so on
```

Also, I want to use it in class based views. I mean, I would like to write view as:

```
class TopicCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = TopicForm

    # ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # some things before creating objects
```

As suggested in comments, I could use two forms. But I don't see any simple way to use two forms in my `TopicCreate` view - I should reimplement all methods belongs to getting form(at least).

### So, my question is:

Is there something already implemented in Django for my requirements? Or is there a better(simpler) way?

**or**

Do you know a simple way with using two forms in class based view? If so, tell me, it could solve my issue too.

Comment: You could combine two modelforms in your view.

Comment: good question i never thinked such. usually create new forms. That is much better to me

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert, I don't see simple way to use two forms with class-based views. Looks like I should re-implement `get_form_class`, `get_form`, etc. Please, tell me, if I'm wrong and simpler way exists. Thank you, anyway, I'll try that you suggest.

Comment: For this i would switch to a function based view, it's just way too many work getting it work in cbv's.

Comment: Function-based views is deprecated, isn't it?

Comment: This may help you: [Using a mixin with a Django form class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114710/using-a-mixin-with-a-django-form-class) (however you why not just use two separate forms like Sudipta suggested?)

Comment: @stellarchariot, Thanks, I'll take a look on it. And, please, look at updated question - I explained why I can't(as I think) use two forms.

Comment: @soon you should make one (1) form for this. The form should handle the _exact_ flow you want. If you have to mix two models then you should make a mixed form (one that you've created yourself). This won't violate DRY as it's is own form for a special usecase.

Comment: @limelights, Not sure if I understood you right. You mean, I should use first form presented in my question?

Comment: @Soon yeah it was a dumb comment and i cant change it. What I meant is that you should make 1 form for this that handles your exact use case. So yes, the first form you presented in your question.

Comment: I don't quite understand the relationship between the form and the models. You have a 1-to-n relationship between `Topic` and `Post`, so if you used the default `ModelForm` for `Post`, you'd get a drop-down list of `Topic`s to choose from. What exactly are you expecting the `Post` form to contain? A `Topic` form on the other hand would have many related `Post`s, so which of them should it show in the form?

Comment: @Aya, I already have the `PostForm` - it contains only `body`. Now I want a `TopicForm` for creating a new `Topic` with a new `Post` - first `Post` in the `Topic`. I don't need a `Post` form, I need a `TopicForm`. Right now I will use first presented form(with copied content) - just to not lose time. Maybe later I'll try to write my own `MagicForm` to create mixed form from multiple models.

Comment: @soon Ahh. I see. So in effect it's a single form that will create two new records. Yeah. There's nothing like that built-in to Django, although there's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569468/django-multiple-models-in-one-template-using-forms).

Answer (score 2):

You can create two separate forms having the required fields, for each model. Then show both forms in the template inside one  html element. Both forms will get rendered and then submitted individually. You can then process the forms separately in the view.

```
class TopicForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ("title", ..)


class PostForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("body", ..)
```

In view:

```
form1 = TopicForm()
form2 = PostForm()
```

In template:

```
<form ...>
{{ form1 }}
{{ form2 }}
</form>
```

You can easily use form.save() and all other functions, without doing it all yourself.

Comment: That's great, but I use class-based views, and, right now, I don't see any simple way to use two forms in it(I should re-implement `get_form_class`, `get_form`, and others). Do you? If yes, tell me, please, that would be very cool.

Comment: @soon Ohk! I haven't started using class-based views. And a quick search does not give any easy solution.
A class-based view can have two forms, but only one of them can be processed at a time. A similar question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276398/multiple-form-classes-in-django-generic-class-views).
Maybe, it'll be easier for you to combine the two forms into one.